# What's debug section in IDA Pro?

Tags: reverse-engineering, disassembly, ida

I try to analyze a dll file with my poor assembly skills, so forgive me if I couldn't achieve something very trivial. My problem is that, while debugging the application, I find the code I'm looking for only in debug session, after I stop the debugger, the address is gone. The dll doesn't look to be obfuscated, as many of the code is readable. Take a look at the [screenshot](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3055964/ida.png). The code I'm looking for is located at address 07D1EBBF in debug376 section. BTW, where did I get this debug376 section?

So my question is, How can I find this function while not debugging?
Thanks

UPDATE

Ok, as I said, as soon as I stop the debugger, the code is vanished. I can't even find it via sequence of bytes (but I can in debug mode). When I start the debugger, the code is not disassembled imediately, I should add a hardware breakpoint at that place and only when the breakpoint will be hit, IDA will show disassembled code. take a look at this [screenshot](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3055964/ida2.gif)
You see the line of code I'm interested in, which is not visible if the program is not running in debug mode. I'm not sure, but I think it's something like unpacking the code at runtime, which is not visible at design time.

Anyway, any help would be appreciated. I want to know why that code is hidden, until breakpoint hit (it's shown as "db 8Bh" etc) and how to find that address without debugging if possible. BTW, could this be a code from a different module (dll)?

Thanks

UPDATE 2

I found out that debug376 is a segment created at runtime. So simple question: how can I find out where this segment came from :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So you see the code in the Debugger Window once your program is running and as you seem not to find the verry same opcodes in the raw Hex-Dump once it's not running any more?

What might help you is taking a **Memory Snapshot**. Pause the program's execution near the instructions you're interested in to make sure they are there, then choose "**Take memory snapshot**" from the "Debugger" Menu. IDA will then ask you wether to copy only the Data found at the segments that are defined as "loder segments" (those the PE loader creates from the predefined table) or "all segments" that seem to currently belong to the debugged program (*including* such that might have been created by an unpacking routine, decryptor, whatever). Go for "**All segments**" and you should be fine seeing memory contents including your *debug segments* (a segment 
created or recognized while debugging) in IDA when not debugging the application.

You can view the list of segements at any time by pressing *Shift+F7* or by clicking "**Segments**" from **View** > **Open subviews**.

Keep in mind that the programm your trying to analyze might choose to create the segment some other place the next time it is loaded to make it harder to understand for you what's going on.

**UPDATE to match your second Question**

When a program is unpacking data from somewhere, it will have to copy stuff somewhere. Windows is a virtual machine that nowadays get's real nasty at you when trying to execute or write code at locations that you're not allowed to. So any program, as long as we're under windows will somehow

1. Register a Bunch of new memory or overwrite memory it already owns. This is usually done by calling something like malloc or so [Your code looks as if it could have been a verry pointer-intensive language... VB perhaps or something object oriented] it mostly boils down to a call to **VirtualAlloc** or **VirtualAllocEx** from Windows's kernel32.dll, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887(v=vs.85).aspx for more detail on it's calling convention.
2. Perhaps set up Windows Exception handling on that and mark the memory range als executable if it wasn't already when calling VirtualAlloc. This would be done by calling **VirtualProtect**, again from kernel32.dll. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366898(v=vs.85).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366786(v=vs.85).aspx for more info on that.

So now, you should take a step trough the programm, starting at its default Entrypoint (OEP) and look for calls tho one of those functions, possibly with the memory protection set to PAGE_EXECUTE or a descendant. After that will possibly come some sort of loop decrypting the memory contents, copying them to their new location. You might want to just step over it, depending on what your interest in the program is by justr placing the cursor after the loop (thick blue line in IDA usually) and clicking "Run to Cursor" from the menu that appears upon right clicking the assembler code.

If that fails, just try placing a Hardware Breakpoint on kernel32.dll's VirtualAlloc and see if you get anything interestin when stepping into the return statement so you end up wherever the execution chain will take you after the Alloc or Protect call.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the Relative Virtual Address of that code, this will allow you to find it again regardless of the load address (pretty handy with almost all systems using ASLR these days). the RVA is generally calculated as `virtual address - base load address = RVA`, however, you might also need to account for the section base as well.

The alternative is to use IDA's rebasing tool to rebase the dll to the same address everytime.

Comment: But I can't find the sequence of bytes after I stop debugging, that code just vanishes, disapears :|

Comment: @Davita: thats why you need to notes its address and the base of the module its in when you start debugging.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm really a starter here. Could you please provide me with a step by step instruction if you dont mind? :( Thank you again very much for your help

Comment: @Davita: unfortunately I only use IDA for static flow analysis, as I prefer using ollydbg for debugging (plus I don't have any x64 apps to debug), there is a book on using IDA for debugging that may be of help.